# How do I drag apps from one home page to another?

Tags: applications, menu, recents-screen, samsung-galaxy-mega-2, samsung-galaxy-s-6-edge+

I upgraded from Galaxy Mega to Galaxy S6 Edge +.

In Mega, I can drag one app from one home page to another without going through the ones in between.

In S6E+, it seems that I have to go through each page. I use folders, but it's still a hassle.

Must I really go through each page? If no, how can I go drag to another page?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is remove the icon, open application manager and drag the icon to the screen you want it at.

You can also leave the icon on the first screen and then remove it after creating a shortcut on the other screen since apps usually don't care how many shortcuts you have.